# Adding timestamp field on existing table

Tags: spring, postgresql

I have a table which already has records inside, I want to alter table to add a new `created` field to store timestamp which should be not updatable and not null. So I'd like to set existing records to current timestamp and newly created records in the future to their own timestamp.

```
@Column(name = "created", updatable = false)
@CreatedDate
private LocalDateTime createdTime;
```

Can I still use `default` after I make field non-upgradable?

```
ALTER TABLE user
    ADD created  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT current_timestamp NOT NULL
```

If not, what should I do?

ps. I use PostgreSQL.